# Calculate button will not display results after inserting if(IsValidData)) in calculate button method

Tags: c#, validation, events, methods, exception

If I remove the if statement in:

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (IsValidData())

            {
                decimal operand1 = Convert.ToDecimal(txtOperand1.Text);
                string operator1 = txtOperator.Text;
                decimal operand2 = Convert.ToDecimal(txtOperand2.Text);
                decimal result = Calculate(operand1, operator1, operand2);

                result = Math.Round(result, 4);
                txtResult.Text = result.ToString();
                txtOperand1.Focus();
            }  
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {               
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n\n" +
            ex.GetType().ToString() + "\n" +
            ex.StackTrace, "Exception");
        }
    }
```

Then the program (a calculator that adds, subtracts, divides, and multiplies) runs okay, but I need the IsValidData method to look for user errors and to display them within a message box. As of right now, the calculate button does not display the results that should be there (1*5 entered and does not display 5, just a blank textbox). I am still trying to grasp creating events/methods, so I believe it must have to do with my logic.

This is what I have completed so far and any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SimpleCalculator
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (IsValidData())
            {
                decimal operand1 = Convert.ToDecimal(txtOperand1.Text);
                string operator1 = txtOperator.Text;
                decimal operand2 = Convert.ToDecimal(txtOperand2.Text);
                decimal result = Calculate(operand1, operator1, operand2);

                result = Math.Round(result, 4);
                txtResult.Text = result.ToString();
                txtOperand1.Focus();

            }  
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {             
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n\n" +
            ex.GetType().ToString() + "\n" +
            ex.StackTrace, "Exception");
        }
    }

    public bool IsValidData()
    {
           return

            //validate the operand1 text box
            IsPresent(txtOperand1, "Operand 1") &&
            IsDecimal(txtOperand1, "Operand 1") &&
            IsWithinRange(txtOperand1, "Operand 1", 0, 1000000) &&

            //validates the operator text box

            IsOperator(txtOperator, "Operator") &&


            //validates the operand 2 text box
            IsPresent (txtOperand2, "Operand 2")&&
            IsDecimal(txtOperand2, "Operand 2") &&
            IsWithinRange(txtOperand2, "Operand 2", 0, 1000000);
    }

    private decimal Calculate(decimal operand1, string operator1,
        decimal operand2)
    {
        decimal result = 0;
        if (operator1 == "+")
            result = operand1 + operand2;
        else if (operator1 == "-")
            result = operand1 - operand2;
        else if (operator1 == "*")
            result = operand1 * operand2;
        else if (operator1 == "/")
            result = operand1 / operand2;
        return result;
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void ClearResult(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.txtResult.Text = "";
    }


    //is present
    public bool IsPresent (TextBox textBox, string name)
    {
        if (textBox.Text == "")

        {
            MessageBox.Show(name + " is a required field.", "Entry Error");
            textBox.Focus();          
        }
        return false;
    }

    //is decimal
    public bool IsDecimal (TextBox textBox, string name)
    {
        decimal number = 0m;

        if (Decimal.TryParse(textBox.Text, out number))
        {
            return true;
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(name + " must be a decimal value.", "Entry Error");
            textBox.Focus();

            return false;
        }
    }

    //is within range
    public bool IsWithinRange (TextBox textBox, string name, decimal min, decimal max)
    {
        decimal number = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox.Text);

        if (number< min || number  >max)

        {
            MessageBox.Show(name + "must be between" + min.ToString()
                + "and" + max.ToString() + ".", "Entry Error");
            textBox.Focus();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    //is a valid operator
    public bool IsOperator (TextBox textBox, string name)

    {            
        if (textBox.Text != "+" || textBox.Text != "-" || textBox.Text != "/" || textBox.Text != "*")

        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid operator in the operator text box.", "Entry Error");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You should use `&&` instead `||` for the check condition in your `IsOperator` function.

```
//is a valid operator
public bool IsOperator (TextBox textBox, string name)
{            
    if (textBox.Text != "+" && textBox.Text != "-" && textBox.Text != "/" && textBox.Text != "*")

    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid operator in the operator text box.", "Entry Error");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```